# index.php not opening

Tags: php

I have a file index.php here:

http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/home/

but when I type this path and press enter It doesn't open index.php hence, if I type

http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/home/index.php

It opens ! What may be the problem ?

Edit: I also have a index.php file here:

http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/staff/

and when I type this path and press enter it opens index.php

then whats the problem with home directory ?

Comment: More details required.  What operating system are you running?  What web server software?

Comment: Check if your `home` folder don't have `index.html` file !!

Comment: I have done some edits. Check out

Comment: Windows WAMP Server @ localhost

Comment: no there is no index.html file within home directory only index.php file and a home.html.php file which i use as a template

Comment: I found solution here http://www.coders.pro/2017/01/got-error-primary-script-unknown-update-php-fpm-apache-2-4/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: I also have a index.php file here:

http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/staff/

and when I type this path and press enter it opens index.php

then whats the problem with home directory ?

Comment: this is my directory index in apache                        'code' DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm 'code'

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk - Is there a `.htaccess` file in your home directory? Does it contain `DirectoryIndex` settings?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DirectoryIndex` file of your webserver (I assume apache now):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

in `httpd.conf`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: I also have a index.php file here:

http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/staff/

and when I type this path and press enter it opens index.php

then whats the problem with home directory ?

Comment: Apache settings : DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache you need to set DirectoryIndex

Comment: I also have a index.php file here:

http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/staff/

and when I type this path and press enter it opens index.php

then whats the problem with home directory ?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at your `httpd.conf`. there should be a line named `DirectoryIndex` wich controls this. It should read like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.pl
```

Comment: I also have a index.php file here:

http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/staff/

and when I type this path and press enter it opens index.php

then whats the problem with home directory ?

Comment: Apache settings : DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a file name index.html in the same path. Or you don't have directory index.

Answer (score 0):

In case of the Apache server I'm using it helped me to rewrite the rule by adding a simple line of code to **.htaccess** file. In your case it would probably be:

```
RewriteRule ^http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/home/$ http://localhost/widget_corp/explore/home/index.php [L]
```